# Undefined method isGranted in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am using a statement from a Symfony2 app in Symfony4:

```
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');         
if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ){
. . .
}
```

I get always error:

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "isGranted" of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage
```

what I am missing?

Comment: do you have already see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36533186/2270041 ?

Comment: Hey Stefano, could our answers help you fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Symfony gives you several ways to enforce authorization, including […] using `isGranted` on the `security.authorization_checker` service directly.
>
> [source](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#authorization-i-e-denying-access)

You should call `isGranted` on the `security.authorization_checker` service, not the `security.token_storage`.

Answer (score 0):

for SF4, according to the docs:

```
public function hello($name)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');

    // ...
}
```

You have to use security.authorization_checker service. And the code above is the same as:

```
public function hello($name, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker)
{
    if (false === $authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Unable to access this page!');
    }

    // ...
}
```

check docs here https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code