# Symfony Easyadmin and FOSUserBundle: Get Role - hasRole()?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, easyadmin

I am currently working in AdminController.php where I need to check the role of the the logged in user. In the UserInterface.php of FOSUserBundle I found the public function `hasRole()`, which does exactly what I need. But in comments it's said to never use the function. Instead the author recommend to use `$authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER');` but on what do I have to call isGranted? Is there any method like $this->getUser() which returns sth. of type AuthorizationChecker?

This is perfectly working: 
`$this->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`

Comment: Are you using only `ROLE_USER` and `ROLE_ADMIN`?

Comment: A user has a one one the following roles: `ROLE_USER`, `ROLE_ADMIN` and  `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`.

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531853/you-have-requested-a-non-existent-service-security-context